# Color edge of a polygon with css

Tags: html, css

I want to outline (2px high) ONLY the top, shaped part of this polygon with the color blue. What is the most effective way to achieve this?

```css
.graph {
    clip-path:polygon(0 78%, 9% 67%, 32% 77%, 56% 60%, 69% 30%, 88% 40%, 100% 20%, 100% 100%,0 100%);
    border:none;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
       <div class="graph"></div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: you mean you want a blue colored line on the edge?

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya yes, but only the top edge

Comment: Does it have to be in the same object? Looks to me as if you just need a path object too

Comment: @smartse yes, because ultimately I want to bring down the opacity of the red object. So I cannot have anything behind it.

Comment: ok but why not in front?

Comment: @smartse It could go in front. But dealing with percentage heights makes it complicated. How would you do it?

Comment: Not sure, but do you need this: https://jsfiddle.net/6wo1yrgf/ . create the same graph with Path of svg.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution but worth a try.

```css
.graph {
    clip-path:polygon(0 78%, 9% 67%, 32% 77%, 56% 60%, 69% 30%, 88% 40%, 100% 20%, 100% 100%,0 100%);
    border:none;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.graph::before {
  content: "";
  clip-path:polygon(0 78%, 9% 67%, 32% 77%, 56% 60%, 69% 30%, 88% 40%, 100% 20%, 100% 100%,0 100%);
  border: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
}

body{
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
       <div class="graph"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That would work but I need the main body to be transparent eventually.

Comment: Well worst scenario would be take body color dynamically and add it in the background under graph::before

Answer (score 0):

Add more points to create only the line. You can introduce a variable to control the thickness:

```css
.graph {
  --b: 5px; /* the thickness */
  
  height: 200px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  background :red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 78%, 9% 67%, 32% 77%, 56% 60%, 69% 30%, 88% 40%, 100% 20%,100% calc(20% + var(--b)),88% calc(40% + var(--b)),69% calc(30% + var(--b)),56% calc(60% + var(--b)),32% calc(77% + var(--b)),9% calc(67% + var(--b)),0 calc(78% + var(--b)))
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph"></div>
```